# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 - Flutter Contacts_services

Tags: flutter, android-contacts, mobile-application

I am very much new to flutter and need help in building my app.

When I run the project, It shoots an error saying: **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0**, I am not able to display any contacts but one, and that isn't even the first contact.

Please help. Thank you.

**My Code:**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
    if (kReleaseMode)
      exit(1);
  };
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter contacts',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Contacts Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Contact> contacts = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getAllContacts();
  }

  getAllContacts() async{
    List<Contact> _contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts()).toList();
    setState(() {
      contacts = _contacts;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Phone Book',
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: contacts.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    Contact contact = contacts[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(contact.displayName),
                      subtitle: Text(
                          contact.phones.elementAt(0).value
                      ),
                      leading: (contact.avatar != null && contact.avatar.length > 0) ?
                      CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: MemoryImage(contact.avatar),
                      ):
                      CircleAvatar(child: Text(contact.initials()),),
                    );
                  },
                )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have all the appropriate dependencies and have also specified the user_permission to READ and WRITE.

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you add the code for ContactsService class?

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you want to make your UI dependent on data from the internet in Flutter you typicaly use `FutureBuilder` if you know the data never changes. You can also use `StreamBuilder` which automaticaly updates when the data from the internet changes E.g. when a new contact is added to the list. Try using one of those in your code.

At the moment your code is not that safe. If the async function `getAllContacts()` finihes before the entire widget is build the app will crash, because you will end up calling the `setState()` function before the state of the widget is build.

You could do something like this:

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Future<List<Contact>> contacts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    contacts = getAllContacts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Contact>>(
        future: contacts,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Contact>> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            //Return a loadingscreen or placeholder widget
          }

          //Access the list of contacts:
          List<Contact> myContacts = snapshot.data; 

          //Return the widget
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Phone Book',
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: myContacts.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        Contact contact = myContacts[index];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(contact.displayName),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              contact.phones.elementAt(0).value
                          ),
                          leading: (contact.avatar != null && contact.avatar.length > 0) ?
                          CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: MemoryImage(contact.avatar),
                          ):
                          CircleAvatar(child: Text(contact.initials()),),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But it also seems like there is something wrong when you call the `getAllContacts()` method. At line: `List<Contact> _contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts()).toList();` it seems odd to call the `toList()` method here. The `ContactService.getContact()` should probably already return a List of contacts

Comment: Okay, so how do I go about it.?